# How can I add a class to a particular inline row based on the date recorded in a field of the row?

Tags: django, class, django-admin, inline

I have an inline model DayOff where I would like to gray out the entire row if the date entered on the DayOff object is a past date. Any idea how to add a class or styling to an entire row, based on the date field recorded in it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a property to your model like so

```
@property
def is_past_date(self):
    return self.date < timezone.now().date():
```

Then in your template just add:

```
<tr class="{% if model.is_past_date %}bg-grey{% else %}bg-white{% endif % }">
```

I made the assumption that you model holds a field called "date" and that your model is called model (otherwise change the code accordingly). Furthermore that you have specified bg-grey and bg-white within your css file.
Of course you can check for other cases in your property as well (for example if the date is between two other dates, etc.), I guess you get the point.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: So how would I change the template, given that this is an admin inline? The property idea looks good, but I'd have to be able to alter whatever the admin is using to build the row.

Comment: Then you will probably have to override/replace the django admin template for your specific inline: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model